# L2 Visa: applying EAD from india

Tags: usa, indian-citizens

I am having L2 visa.
1. Can i apply for EAD from India.if yes then EAD application require I94 document which will show Departure record. so is there any chance of rejection because I am applying online from india

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply from India because you will not be in a status that allows EAD. To be in L2 status, you need to enter the US with a L2 visa (or change from a different status into L2), and be in the US.